# loading iframe source dynamically

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I have a few Google map embeds on my page; these are making my page slow, so I wanted to load them after the loading of the page, so I was trying something like this. Unfortunately the map's iframe source changes, but the map doesn't load inside, its just blank.

e.g. link:

```html
<iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Megarugas+Banquet+and+Lawn,+Opp.+Chandivali+studio,&amp;aq=&amp;sll=19.127228,72.865035&amp;sspn=0.013259,0.022724&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Megarugas+Banquet+and+Lawn,+Opp.+Chandivali+studio,&amp;hnear=&amp;t=m&amp;cid=15174344858031542989&amp;ll=19.115165,72.894802&amp;spn=0.024329,0.025663&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Megarugas+Banquet+and+Lawn,+Opp.+Chandivali+studio,&amp;aq=&amp;sll=19.127228,72.865035&amp;sspn=0.013259,0.022724&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Megarugas+Banquet+and+Lawn,+Opp.+Chandivali+studio,&amp;hnear=&amp;t=m&amp;cid=15174344858031542989&amp;ll=19.115165,72.894802&amp;spn=0.024329,0.025663&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

HTML:

```html
<iframe id="blabla"></iframe>
```

JS:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
   if ($('#blabla').length <= 0) { return; }  // to avoid errors in case the element doesn't exist on the page / removed.
   $('#blabla').attr('src','//example.com/page');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The src will not be parsed inside the script, you must replace all occurencies of `&amp;` with `&`

You don't need to do this on your own.

Create some element, set the html to the src and then retrieve the text of the element:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('#blabla').attr('src',$('<span/>').html('https://example.com/page').text());
});
```

**Additional Note:**
You don't need to check the length of `$('#blabla')` , you will not receive an error when a jQuery-object is empty.